# Webpshere Application Server wsadmin script to disable cookies settings in a deployed application

Tags: scripting, websphere, jython, wsadmin, jacl

I have several modules(say Mod1) under my deployed application's(say App) manage modules and for the modules Mod1 I have to do these things:

Under General properties, 
1. Check the box Override session management and click Apply.
2. Click the Enable cookies link under Session tracking mechanism.
3. Under General properties, uncheck the box Set session cookies to HTTP Only to help prevent cross-site scripting attacks and click Apply.

So far I could get myself  to only check or uncheck the Override session management option under my application by first getting its id using the following code, but I am not able to figure out how to do the above 3 things for a module under my application.

```
    appName = AdminConfig.getid('/Deployment:FileNetEngine/')
    depObject = AdminConfig.showAttribute(appName, 'deployedObject')
    sessionMgrAttrs = [['sessionManagement', [['enable', 'true']]]]
    AdminConfig.create('ApplicationConfig', depObject, sessionMgrAttrs)
    AdminConfig.save()
```

It would be great if I can get an answer to this in JACL, as I have all my scripts in jacl and I was trying with jython only for this piece.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your problem is solved already.

I had the same problem, and I solved it with [this post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/556690/Websphere/WSadmin-set-sessionManagement-cookiePath-WebModule). Instead of "WebModuleConfig", I configure the "ApplicationConfig".

```
appName = AdminConfig.getid('/Deployment:testWebapp_war/')
depObject = AdminConfig.showAttribute(appName, 'deployedObject')
sessionMgrAttrs = [['sessionManagement', [['enable', 'true'], ['defaultCookieSettings', [['path','/xxx'], ['useContextRootAsPath', 'false'], ['name', 'JSESSIONID'], ['httpOnly', 'false']]]]]]
AdminConfig.create('ApplicationConfig', depObject, sessionMgrAttrs)
AdminConfig.save()
```